# Trying to use for...in loop and adding an if/else statement and keeps saying i am missing a ")"

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, for-in-loop

```
const testScores = {
  John : 99,
  Jess : 78,
  Ryan : 89,
  Tom : 62,
  Jane: 57,
  Ben: 83
};

for (person in testScores){
  
       if (testScores[person] > 90){
       console.log("Well done "+ person ". You scored " + testScores[person])
  };

       else{
       console.log(person + " scored " + testScores[person])};
}
```

Comment: You have a bad string concatenation in the first `console.log` and you have a semicolon before the `else` declaration. correct those and you'll be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First is typo, you forgot to add the `+` between `person` and `". You scored "`
- Second you are using `;` after if block, because of that, it program didn't compile.

```js
const testScores = {
  John: 99,
  Jess: 78,
  Ryan: 89,
  Tom: 62,
  Jane: 57,
  Ben: 83
};

for (person in testScores) {
  if (testScores[person] > 90) {
    console.log("Well done " + person + ". You scored " + testScores[person]);
  } else {
    console.log(person + " scored " + testScores[person]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! appreciate the help

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if this is the answer that you want.